# FB PHP SDK Get friends who authorised app by fbid or accesstoken

Tags: php, api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, phalcon

I'm working on an iPhone App API written with Phalcon Framwework and Facebook PHPSDK v2. All of the authentication is done on the client and once the fb access token is verified by the server a separate HMAC auth is set up between the client and server. 
My end goal is to return a list of friends ids, names and profile pic urls, who have authorised an app given a new users users fbid or acccess token. I have used this library to include the SDK in my Phalcon application https://github.com/geass/Phalcon-Facebook-Library

I've already scoured SO for an anwer and tried a few graph requests but they don't seem to work.

I have used the following FQL found readily on SO in the graph API explorer:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 123456) AND is_app_user = 1
```

which seems to work, if the access token is valid.

when i try to use the same FQL in the SKD im not sure how I can apply the access token, simply doing:

```
 function getFriendsUsingApp($fbId){

        $params = array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        //'query' => "select pic_square from user where uid=$fbId",
        'query' => "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $fbId) AND is_app_user = 1",
         );

        $result = $this->_facebook->api($params);

        return($result);

       }
```

This result in the following error:

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Exception: 102: Requires user session
  thrown in 
**D:\library\Social\sdk\base_facebook.php** on line 
**1271**

How can I get this information given either the fb id or Access token or both?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your Access Token is created and valid? Get it, and debug it within https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: yes, i took the token from the test users on the app, when i try the FQL in the debugger i get a good result

Comment: don't forget sessions expire. Do you used that access token right after using it in Facebook Debug?

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found was to invest the time in getting the FBSDK to run properly in Phalcon and then use a graph request (which neatly deals with a lot of issues i was having with using HTTPS in file_get_contents()). Somenone else then pointed that out that the FB API docs i say you can just add the access token on the end of a GET graph request.

In my facebook library file:

```
function getFriendsUsingAppIds($fbId, $accessToken){           
        return $this->_facebook->api("$fbId/friends?fields=installed&access_token==$accessToken");

    }
```

This gave

```
[0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 305232
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 305391
                )
            [633] => Array
                (
                    [installed] => 1
                    [id] => 100005007310527
                )
```

I completely missed row 633 at first and assumed i was just getting a list of all friends.

I then removed the rows which didnt have installed set with a simple foreach.